# Preventing indent of tables with border-collapse, separate

Tags: html, css, border-spacing

I have some very basic html:

```
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Addressed to</th>
        <th>Sender</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe smith</td>
        <td>Ralph Lauren</td>
        <td>$200</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe smith</td>
        <td>Ralph Lauren</td>
        <td>$200</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Now, I'd like to add spacing between my table rows and columns, so I add this css:

```
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px 10px;
}
```

Great.  Except now the table itself is no longer flush left with the 2 paragraphs.

[image]

My question is how can the table get the needed spacing but NOT the indent, or how can apply the least CSS to overcome the indent?

See this code at http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/9mzzdsrn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick solution (especially if it's a static site) just knock the margin back by 20px (the same as the indent on the table)

```
margin-left:-20px;
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mzzdsrn/2/) is a working example

Comment: yeah, i thought so, but some part of me thought there might be a more "high tech" way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `border-spacing` you can just set the margin on the table and then also set padding to each row to achieve the same effect with the text flush left

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin-right:20px;
}
td {
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin-right:20px;
}
td {
    padding:10px;
}
```